# how to use std::sort to sort an array based on values returned by a certain function while passed the elements of the array to be sorted?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

how to use std::sort to sort an array based on values returned by a certain function while passed the elements of the array to be sorted?

```
class Board{
    //members
};
int score(int num,Board b){
   return b.evaluate(num);
   //lets say score() function returns an evaluation based 
   //on num and Board type object b. 
}

void main(){
    Board b;
    int num_array[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::sort(num_array.begin(),num_array.end());  
        //how to use std::sort to sort num_array based on values returned
        //by score() while passed elements of num_array
}
```

is there a way to pass the function as the third argument in std::sort or does it need to be resolved some other way?

Comment: you use [the overload with Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (3rd)

Comment: By the way, `void main` is nonstandard C++. It should be `int main` instead.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 It isn't just nonstandard, it is nonconforming. Even when implementations provide alternative forms of `main` they are still always required to have the `int` return type.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what exactly you're trying to do with `Board` and `score` so it would be easier to explain what you can do with reference to your specific situation.

Comment: For fun, use the C++20 ranges::sort with a projection function. More seriously, assuming `score` is costly, create an array with the scores, then sort both arrays based on the values in the second one (you can find questions explaining how to do that on this site).

Answer (score 5):

Use a lambda, and capture the board by reference to use inside of it:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>

struct Board {
  int grades[10] = {90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0};

  int evaluate(int i) const { return grades[i]; }
};

int score(int i, Board const& board) { return board.evaluate(i); }

int main() {
  Board b;
  int num_array[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  std::sort(std::begin(num_array), std::end(num_array),
            [&b](auto const& e1, auto const& e2) {
              return score(e1, b) < score(e2, b);
            });

  for (auto& e : num_array) std::printf("%d ", e);
  std::putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an overload of `std::sort` that takes a third argument which is a function:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );           (before C++20)
---------------------------------------------------------
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
constexpr void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp ); (since C++20)
```

The rules of the parameter `comp` are as follows (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)):

> `comp` -
>  comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies
> the requirements of `Compare`) which returns ​`true` if the first argument
> is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.
>
> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the
> following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> While the signature does not need to have `const &`, the function must
> not modify the objects passed to it and must be able to accept all
> values of type (possibly `const`) `Type1` and `Type2` regardless of value
> category (thus, `Type1 &` is not allowed, nor is `Type1` unless for Type1
> a move is equivalent to a copy *(since C++11)*). The types `Type1` and
> `Type2` must be such that an object of type `RandomIt` can be dereferenced
> and then implicitly converted to both of them.

I'm not exactly sure what `score` does but it seems like it wouldn't work on its own as a function because, for one, both arguments have to be convertible from `int` in your case. So depending on how you need to use it, you could maybe wrap it in another function or lambda.

Assuming `num_array` is, say, an array of players and `score` checks the score of each person, your program could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // std::begin, std::end

class Board
{
    int scores[10] = {40, 20, 90, 50, 10, 30, 50, 80, 90, 0};
public:
    int evaluate(int num) {return scores[num];}
};

int score(int num, Board b)
{
   return b.evaluate(num);
}

int main()
{
    Board b;
    int players[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    // sort by highest score player to lowest score player
    std::sort(std::begin(players), std::end(players), [&b](const auto &l, const auto &r){
        return score(l, b) > score(r, b);
    });

    for (const auto &i : players)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I'd encourage keeping the answer's momentum going and completing the answer with the code that would actually answer the question.

Comment: @sweenish unfortunately I'm not entirely sure what OP's intent is with `Board` and `score`. I could post a somewhat unrelated example, but It may not be as good.

Comment: Seems likely that they want to sort the array in terms of `score(x, b)` where `b` is the `Board b;` from `main` and `x` is the element being sorted. A lambda capturing `b` would be appropriate.

Comment: Something that shows a lambda that relies on a function call in action ought to be sufficient.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux my main confusion was with what exactly `evaluate` did. I've added one example assuming `num_array` is an array of players, but admittedly I feel like now it looks a bit too similar to Ayxan's. Can't think of anything else OP's program is meant to do. I think it would be helpful if OP explained better about whatever they are trying to do so a relevant example can be provided instead of a guess, so I've requested OP to provide more details.